# having persistent header underneeth another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following JQUERY to show and update a header on my HTML page.

```
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
   $(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this);

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "visible"
           });
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
           });      
       };
   });
}

// DOM Ready      
$(function() {

   var clonedHeaderRow;

   $(".persist-area").each(function() {
       clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
       clonedHeaderRow
         .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
         .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
         .addClass("floatingHeader");

   });

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
```

this works and the header comes down with the page.

However further up the page i have another div which i would like to take down while scrolling as well.

If i add the same code i use for the other header they will start on top when loading the page which is not what i want.

how can i achieve this?

**Webpage**

U can find what i have so far here :

```
http://145.24.222.229:8088/moederborden/
```

if u scroll down the header with "HOME, SHOP, FAQ, CONTACT, Winkelmandje"  Wil come down with it.

What i want is that as soon as it reaches the left Element which says "Merk" it takes that one down too

Comment: Please include HTML code and demo if possible

Comment: I added the url where u can see what i have so far, a demo is to hard to show because my css consists out of 6000 rules of code.

Comment: "HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /moederborden/index.jsp at line 96" - If you can't add the specific code for the problem, it's really tough to solve. And as you can see, links are not a good option

Comment: My bad, reload the page, it is a mistake on the cookie side. it tries to read a cookie where there hasnt been set one yet.

Comment: Well at least you should set the z-index of your home, shop, faq div higher than the rest of your page. Now it fails to overlap the 'merk' part